# mongod doesn't stop (docker debian:wheezy)

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Then I build the image:

```
docker build -t my/image .
```

and try to start and stop the server:

```
$ docker run -it my/image
root@35ba8193f979:/# service mongod start
[ ok ] Starting database: mongod.
root@35ba8193f979:/# service mongod stop
[FAIL] Stopping database: mongod failed!
```

As you can see, mongod fails to stop.  I can verify this by running `ps` and grepping for the mongod process; it's still there.

Here's the logs:

```
root@fce8d9638ce4:/# cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log 
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=19 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=fce8d9638ce4
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-09-20T05:01:02.874+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-09-20T05:01:02.893+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-09-20T05:01:03.087+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2016-09-20T05:01:03.087+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-09-20T05:01:03.156+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

I've googled for a solution already; most of the posts I find are very old, or don't describe the same problem as mine.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with `service mongod stop` since internally it calls a command which looks similar to:

`start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile /var/run/mongod.pid --user mongodb --exec /usr/bin/mongod`

but the `start-stop-daemon` command somehow cannot find the executable `/usr/bin/mongod`, so it failed to stop the process. You can see the service script in `/etc/init.d/mongod`.

The solution that I found to be working is to call it without `--exec` directly from the command line:

`start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile /var/run/mongod.pid`

and that seems to be able to stop the service properly.

I believe this issue is not limited to MongoDB, since I found multiple references about services not able to be stopped.